# Error installing appium

Tags: macos, python, node.js

Following is my log:

```
yaoweiqideMBP:lib yaoweiqi$ npm -g install appium 
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.0.1: Not Ready For Production
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
/usr/local/bin/appium -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js

> heapdump@0.3.12 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/heapdump
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /Users/yaoweiqi/anaconda3/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:381:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:610:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/heapdump
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: heapdump@0.3.12 (node_modules/appium/node_modules/heapdump):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: heapdump@0.3.12 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ appium@1.10.0
updated 1 package in 44.128s


   ╭───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                                               │
   │       New minor version of npm available! 6.4.1 → 6.5.0       │
   │   Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v6.5.0   │
   │               Run npm install -g npm to update!               │
   │                                                               │
   ╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

And I cannot find appium in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/

Comment: Apparently `node-gyp` doesn't properly support Python 3, but I am too lazy to figure out what the resolution from this thread is: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1337

Answer (score 1):

Problem is python version of npm. So change that to python2 would solve it.

```
npm config set python python2.7
```